# Flex box won't scale to width of entire page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net, flexbox

I've tried setting `width: 100%;` for the container flexbox (`display: flex;`), but it only gets as long as the items I have within the flex container and subsequent divs wrap to the right of this container on the same line. I've tried setting the new divs to `float: left`, and `clear: both` but nothing seems to work. The flex container won't take up the whole row and the next tags are not wrapping down to the next line. Here's the css and markup:

```
.container {
display: flex;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
align-items:center;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
width: 100%;
clear: both;
}

.item {
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
}

<div id="mainContainer" class="container" >
        <div id="divRegistration" class="item">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRegistration" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Text="Register" OnClick="btnRegistration_Click" ></asp:Button>
        </div>
        <div id="divSchedule" class="item">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSchedule" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Text="Schedule" OnClick="btnSchedule_Click" ></asp:Button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `#divSchedule` you want in next line?

Comment: Problem seems to be in parent of <div id="mainContainer" class="container" >, please share the entire code.

Comment: Please use inspector and see if any other styles are overriding